# How does Excel Interop's RefreshAll() method work?

Tags: c#, multithreading, excel, excel-interop

There are bunch of excel files. Each of the excel file has various Pivot tables that are connected to SQL Server Analysis (SSAS) cubes. On an average, each file takes around 30 to 60 minutes to refresh, when done manually. I am automating this writing C# program.

Iterating over each file, these are steps:

- instantiate excel application
- open the workbook
- call the .RefreshAll() method
- close the workbook
- quit excel application.

Currently, I have done sequential implementation. No multithreading. I open process explorer and I see that for the excel process the CPU is utilized for around 1 to 2% when the file refresh is in progress.

My question is will running these steps on multiple threads bring down the total time of the program? Is .RefreshAll() method IO intensive? If so, will IO become bottleneck for all my multiple threads?

Comment: I'm not sure if anyone can answer that question. Since the RefreshAll method is going to be pulling data back from your sql server, it is possible that the bottleneck is on the sql server or with your network.

Comment: Excel interop is single-threaded.  Even if you call a method from a worker thread then it still executes on the same thread on which you created the Application object.  The only way to get ahead is to create multiple Application objects, you'll start Excel.exe for each.  But do keep in mind that this only buys you more cpu cycles, apparently that is not the bottleneck when you get only 2% usage.

Comment: @Hans Passant - All the steps mentioned in the question are being executed by one worker thread. So, both excel instance creation and RefreshAll() method are being executed by the same thread.